# sqlite2: Joining max values per column from another table (subquery reference)?

Tags: join, subquery, max, sqlite2

I'm using the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE datas (d_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name_id numeric, countdata numeric);
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(1,1,20);  //(NULL,1,20);
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(2,1,47);  //(NULL,1,47);
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(3,2,36);  //(NULL,2,36);
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(4,2,58);  //(NULL,2,58);
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(5,2,87);  //(NULL,2,87);
CREATE TABLE names (n_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name text);
INSERT INTO names VALUES(1,'nameA'); //(NULL,'nameA');
INSERT INTO names VALUES(2,'nameB'); //(NULL,'nameB');
```

What I would like to do, is to select all values (rows) of `names` - to which all columns of `datas` will be appended, for the row where `datas`.`countdata` is maximum for `n_id` (and of course, where `name_id = n_id`).

I can somewhat get there with the following query:

```
sqlite> .header ON

sqlite> SELECT * FROM names AS n1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT d_id, name_id, countdata FROM datas AS d1 
        WHERE d1.countdata IN (
            SELECT MAX(countdata) FROM datas 
            WHERE name_id=1 
            ) 
        ) AS p1 ON n_id=name_id;

n1.n_id|n1.name|p1.d_id|p1.name_id|p1.countdata
1|nameA|2|1|47
2|nameB|||
```

... however - obviously - it only works for a single row (the one explicitly set by `name_id=1`).

The problem is, the SQL query fails whenever I try to somehow reference the "current" `n_id`:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM names AS n1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT d_id, name_id, countdata FROM datas AS d1 
        WHERE d1.countdata IN (
            SELECT MAX(countdata) FROM datas 
            WHERE name_id=n1.n_id 
            ) 
        ) AS p1 ON n_id=name_id;

SQL error: no such column: n1.n_id
```

Is there any way of achieving what I want in Sqlite2??

Thanks in advance,

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, well - that wasn't trivial at all, but here is a solution:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM names AS n1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
            SELECT d1.* 
            FROM datas AS d1, ( 
                SELECT max(countdata) as countdata,name_id 
                FROM datas 
                GROUP BY name_id
                ) AS ttemp 
            WHERE d1.name_id = ttemp.name_id AND d1.countdata = ttemp.countdata 
        ) AS p1 ON n1.n_id=p1.name_id;


n1.n  n1.name       p1.d_id     p1.name_id  p1.countdata                       
----  ------------  ----------  ----------  -----------------------------------
1     nameA         2           1           47                                 
2     nameB         5           2           87
```

Well, hope this ends up helping someone, :) 
Cheers!

**Notes**: note that just calling max(countdata) screws up competely `d_id`:

```
sqlite> select d_id,name_id,max(countdata) as countdata from datas group by name_id;

d_id  name_id       countdata 
----  ------------  ----------
3     2             87        
1     1             47
```

so to get correct corresponding `d_id`, we must do `max()` on `datas` separately - and then perform sort of an intersect with the full `datas` (*except that intersect in sqlite requires that there are equal number of columns in both datasets, which is not the case here - and even if we made it that way, as seen above `d_id` will be wrong, so intersect will not work*).

One way to do that is in using a sort of a temporary table, and then utilize a multiple table SELECT query so as to set conditions between full `datas` and the subset returned via `max(countdata)`, as shown below:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE ttemp AS SELECT max(countdata) as countdata,name_id FROM datas GROUP BY name_id;
sqlite> SELECT d1.*, ttemp.* FROM datas AS d1, ttemp WHERE d1.name_id = ttemp.name_id AND d1.countdata = ttemp.countdata;

d1.d  d1.name_id    d1.countda  ttemp.coun  ttemp.name_id                      
----  ------------  ----------  ----------  -----------------------------------
2     1             47          47          1                                  
5     2             87          87          2                                  

sqlite> DROP TABLE ttemp;
```

or, we can rewrite the above so a SELECT subquery (sub-select?) is used, like this:

```
sqlite> SELECT d1.* FROM datas AS d1, (SELECT max(countdata) as countdata,name_id FROM datas GROUP BY name_id) AS ttemp WHERE d1.name_id = ttemp.name_id AND d1.countdata = ttemp.countdata;

d1.d  d1.name_id    d1.countda
----  ------------  ----------
2     1             47        
5     2             87
```